# Can I use GitLab with external/remote repository?

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a git repository, I want to start managing it using GitLab. Is it possible to "connect" GitLab to this repository without actually moving the repository to be hosted on the GitLab server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, if you manage it with GitLab, that means a bare repo with its history will be created in the  `/home/git/repositories/` folder ([its default path](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/833bc305933bbf7b8b06d5464ae5716ccbe82674/config/gitlab.yml.example#L213)).